# Custom nginx config for PHP Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web server environment that uses a PHP preconfigured platform.  I want to nginx to pass the request to a proxy server.  Here's what I have in `.ebextensions/nginx.config`:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        sub.mysite.com;
        listen 80;

        location = / {
          rewrite ^ http://www.google.com;
        }

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://****.elasticbeanstalk.com;
        }
      }
```

File `/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf` is created on the server.  When I visit `sub.mysite.com` I am not directed to Google but instead my app, so it seems the nginx config is not loaded.  I've seen other answers that state to do `sudo service nginx reload` to restart nginx, but I get `nginx: unrecognized service`.

Comment: The issue is that the SW package I am using has an .htaccess file in its root directory, so Beanstalk uses Apache.  I'm not sure if PHP on Beanstalk can use nginx, but I added ```RewriteCond``` and ```RewriteRule``` to the .htaccess file statements to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have a file at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb`? The Ruby version of ElasticBeanstalk uses that file to configure nginx.

If the PHP version is the same, then you should be able to insert your configuration there, although you'll want to do it using `sed` rather than installing a whole new file.

Comment: The file is not there for me.